# How to display a queried list of file and folder paths on a windows explorer display on C# .net framework?

Tags: c#, .net

How to convert a queried list of file and folder paths a windows explorer display (which shows all path and date modified and can be right clicked and double clicked) on  C# .net framework?

For example; imagine that there is a list of file and folder paths. Right now I think that those paths should be displayed on a "web browser" (in C# tool box)

For an example, this is already done with this software.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) on how to post a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example. Showing what you've tried (with code) is usually highly encouraged.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question correctly, you have to declare a class which will have have properties to keep the value of FileName, FilePath, Size and DateModified. The collection of file will provide the file attributes which then can be iterated as a list and assigned those values to the properties as defined in that class.

Comment: But right now I think this can be done using the "web browser" like element easily. Am I right? But I don't exactly know to make it happen?